# Regarding Sorting MultiDimensional Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, collections, c#-2.0

I am trying to figure out a way to correctly sort a bunch of different arraylists. 
I am publishing content articles and every value [0] in an arraylist will relate to every other value [0]. and so on. Each element makes up the collective parts of a complete content item.

Now, the last element, popularity, is the amount of clicks an item has received. How do I 
do a sort of the content items based on popularity without mixing up the html for each article?

****EDIT*** I am limited by the .NET 2.0 Framework at Work*

Below is the code... thanks.

```
public class MultiDimDictList : Dictionary<string, ArrayList> { } 

myDicList.Add("fly", a_fly);
myDicList.Add("img", a_img);
myDicList.Add("bar", a_bar);
myDicList.Add("meter", a_meter);
myDicList.Add("block", a_block);
myDicList.Add("popularity", a_pop);
```

Comment: Is there any reason your are storing a dictionary of ArrayLists rather than an List of dictionaries?

Comment: Hi Bob, no not at all. If that works better, I am open to suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the following code you can convert your existing dictionary of arraylists into a collection of Dictionaries and thus allowing a simple sort using Linq OrderBy

```
// Get the shortest arraylist length (they should be equal this is just a paranoia check!)
var count=myDicList.Values.Min(x=>x.Count); 
// Get the collection of Keys
var keys=myDicList.Keys;
// Perform the conversion
var result=Enumerable.Range(0,count).Select(i=>keys.Select(k=>new {Key=k,Value=myDicList[k][i]}).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key,x=>x.Value)); 

var sorted=result.OrderByDescending(x=>x["popularity"]).ToList()
```

-- EDIT VERSION FOR .NET 2.0

First you need a comparer class

```
class PopularityComparison : IComparer<Dictionary<string,object>> {
    private bool _sortAscending;

    public PopularityComparison(bool sortAscending) {
        _sortAscending = sortAscending;
    }

    public int Compare(Dictionary<string, object> x, Dictionary<string, object> y) {
        object xValue = x["popularity"];
        object yValue = y["popularity"];

        // Sort Ascending
        if (_sortAscending) {
            return Comparer.Default.Compare(xValue, yValue);
        } else {
            return Comparer.Default.Compare(yValue, xValue);
        }

    }
}
```

Then you can use the following code

```
// Get the shortest arraylist length (they should be equal this is just a paranoia check!) 
// Replacement for min 
int count = int.MaxValue;
foreach (ArrayList a in myDicList.Values) if (a.Count < count) count = a.Count;
// Get the collection of Keys 
Dictionary<string, ArrayList>.KeyCollection keys = myDicList.Keys;
// Perform the conversion 
List<Dictionary<string, object>> result = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>(count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>(keys.Count);
  foreach (string key in keys) row.Add(key, myDicList[key][i]);
  result.Add(row);
}
```

And then finally to sort in ascending popularity order

```
result.Sort(new PopularityComparison(true));
```

or Descending order

```
result.Sort(new PopularityComparison(true));
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. I unfortunately cannot use LINQ or predicates - I am forced to use .NET 2.0 at work. Is there an example you could provide that uses that framework? I'd appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I feel for you!  I'll see if I can produce a non linq version

Comment: @Code Sherpa - New version that compilers under .Net 2.0

Comment: Thank You Bob! Just ran it and worked perfectly! I owe you big time... much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, being forced to move from .NET 4.0 to 2.0 (in my current gig) took some getting used to... :)

Comment: Hi Bob... I have a follow-up question. If I want to assign the results to a page control, how exactly would I access the control saved in the dictionary collection? I have tried : div.Controls.Add((HtmlGenericControl)result[j]["fly"]); but that produces an HttpException. I think I am not casting correctly?

Comment: @Code Sherpa Could you provide the Message of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I'd think it would be better to have an object containing your keys as properties, then a single collection with each item you'd have in your array lists.

This way you'd have a single collection sort, which becomes trivial if using Linq.OrderBy().

something like...

```
public class Article
{
   public string Fly{get;set;}
   public string Img{get;set;}
   // etc.
   public float Popularity{get;set;}
}
```

Then...

```
List<Article> articles = ... get from somewhere, or convert from your array lists.
List<Article> sorted = articles.OrderBy(a=>a.Popularity).ToList();
```

Please excuse the napkin code here... I'll update it if you need more detail.

An example using non-linq.

Create an implementation of IComparer.

```
public class ArticleComparer : IComparer<Article>
{
    public bool Accending { get; set; }

    public int Compare(Article x, Article y)
    {
        float result = x.Popularity - y.Popularity;

        if (!Accending) { result *= -1; }

        if (result == 0) { return 0; }
        if (result > 0) return 1;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Then when you go to sort the List, you can do something like the following.

```
ArticleComparer comparer = new ArticleComparer();
comparer.Accending = false;
articles.Sort(comparer);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. Per my comments to Jim and Bob, I unfortunately cannot use LINQ or predicates - I am forced to use .NET 2.0 at work. What would be the best solution given my framework limitation? Sorry - I really should have mentioned that when I posted...

Comment: You can use the same approach, but with List<T>.Sort() instead. I'll add a quick example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would be much easier if you had a list of article objects, each of which contained properties for `fly`, `img`, `bar`, `popularity`, etc. But if you really have to store things using this inside-out approach, then the only way you can sort the content items based on popularity is to create another array (or list) to hold the order.

Create a new list and populate it with sequential indexes:

```
List<int> OrderedByPopularity = new List<int>();
ArrayList popList = myDicList["popularity"];
for (int i = 0; i < popList.Count; ++i)
{
    OrderedByPopularity.Add(i);
}
```

Now you have a list that contains the indexes of the items in the popularity list. Now you can sort:

```
OrderedByPopularity.Sort((i1, i2) => return popList[i1].CompareTo(popList[i2]););
```

But that gives you the least popular article first. If you want to reverse the sort so that `OrderedByPopularity[0]` is the most popular item:

```
OrderedByPopularity.Sort((i1, i2) => { return popList[i2].CompareTo(popList[i1]);});
```

Really, though, you should look into restructuring your application. It's much easier to work with objects that have properties rather than trying to maintain parallel arrays of properties.

If you have to do this in .NET 2.0, declare the `poplist` array at class scope (rather than method scope), and create a comparison method.

```
ArrayList poplist;
void MyMethod()
{
    List<int> OrderedByPopularity = new List<int>();
    popList = myDicList["popularity"];
    for (int i = 0; i < popList.Count; ++i)
    {
        OrderedByPopularity.Add(i);
    }
    OrderedByPopularity.Sort(PopularityComparison);
    // ...
}

int PopularityComparison(int i1, int i2)
{
    return ((int)popList[i2]).CompareTo((int)popList[i1]);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could create a collection of popularity-to-index mapping, order the new collection based on popularity, then read by order of index in the collection.

Comment: Thanks Jim, this looks like an elegant solution. Unfortunately I stupidly forgot to mention that I am limited by .NET 2.0 - would this be possible without the use of predicates?

Comment: @Code Sherpa: You can do this in .NET 2.0. See my edited response.

Comment: Hi Jim. I tried your code but CompareTo does not work. I think the problem is that it is operating on an ArrayList and when you say popList[i2].CompareTo(i2) you are calling a function on object which does not exist. Is that correct? Can you tell me how to get around this?

Comment: @Code Sherpa: You have to cast the items returned from `popList`. See my corrected `PopularityComparison` method.